# Unable load data from local json file present in solution of visual studio 2012

Tags: jquery, visual-studio-2012

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script data-require="jquery@*" data-semver="3.0.0" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script type="text/JavaScript">
         $select = $('#people');
         //request the JSON data and parse into the select element
         $.ajax({
             type:'GET',
             url: 'simple.json',
             dataType:'JSON',
             success:function(data){
                 //clear the current content of the select
                 $select.html('');
                 //iterate over the data and append a select option
                 $.each(data.employees, function(key, val){
                     $select.append('<option >' + val.firstName+ '</option>');
                 })
             },
             error:function(){
                 //if there is an error append a 'none available' option
                 $select.html('<option >none available</option>');
             }
         });
         </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <select id="people"></select>
  </body>

</html>
```

This is My working plunker,here i am read the data from local json file.
https://plnkr.co/edit/Ys2xxOn1oUCeNL3wqcvJ?p=preview

But when iam trying the same task in My visual studio,the data cannot be
loaded from local json file present in solution explorer of visual studio 2012.

Comment: This has probably to do with `url: 'simple.json'`, which will result in a relative path. Try setting an absolute path by using a forward slash, e.g. `url: '/simple.json'` or `url: '/data/simple.json'` or whereever your file is. Look into your console (Network tab) to see which path the browser is trying to access.

Comment: even i am trying the url:'/simple.json',i didn't get the output.

Comment: Like I said, look into your console. If the file can't be found you should see a 404 error and the full path that's requested from the server. If the file is loaded (a 20x or 30x status) it's also possible that your DOM is not yet ready when your JS is executed. In that case wrap your script in `$( document ).ready(...)`.

Comment: hi , i am getting the error like the resource cannot be found in console.

Comment: and also  placed my script in $(document).ready(){}